# Sequence of 1's and 0's python bits

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

In java, to get a sequence of 1s and 0s in the form of a binary number, you can do the following

```
(-1 << (4))
```

while will give me the result

```
11110000
```

Since python does not support signed ints, what is the equivalent way of doing this in python? Ideally, I would prefer to do this without any external library.

Comment: What's wrong with `0xf << 4`?

Comment: What about `0xf0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
>>> bin(0xf << 4)[2:]
'11110000'
>>>
```

**Or,**

```
>>> print ('{0:b}'.format(0xf << 4))
11110000
>>> '{0:b}'.format(0xf << 4)
'11110000'
>>>
```

Comment: A better way to get the binary digits without the prefix is `format(0xf << 4, 'b')`.

Comment: So, is 0xf here just the hex representation of -1?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun, no. 0xF is binary 00001111. The shift left part shifts the content 4 bits to the left: 00001111 << 1 makes it 00011110, while 00001111 << 4 makes it 11110000. You could as well use 0xF0 = binary 11110000 if that's all what you need.